# Run Cross compiled C app that uses shared library for android device

Tags: android, c, gcc, makefile, shared-libraries

I couldn't find working example to the following:

I created shared library composed from the code below:

foo.c:
    #include

```
#include "foo.h"

void foo(void)
{
    printf("Hello, I'm a shared library\n");
}
```

and foo.h is the interface:

```
#ifndef __FOO_H__
#define __FOO_H__

void foo(void);

#endif
```

the "foo" code reside under subdirectory foo

Compiled using (I'll drop elaborated make options for the sake of simplicity):

```
#CROSS_COMPILE is:
#/usr/local/toolchain/arm-2010q1/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
CC := $(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc 
$(CC) -fPIC -c foo.c -o foo.o
$(CC) -shared -o libfoo.so foo.o
```

when building it- libfoo.so created successfully.

main.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

And build the app using:

```
$(CC) -c main.c -o main.o
$(CC) main.o -Lfoo -lfoo -o test
```

So far- all OK I get the executable and pushed it to /data/local/tmp/.

Now, I tried all the below without success (got the error: test: no such file or directory)

1. adb push libfoo.so to /system/lib or /system/lib64
2. copy to /data/local/tmp/ and set LD_LIBRARY_PATH accordingly

Anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: I had a problem similar to this recently... I _think_ I used `ldd` and/or `strace` to figure out exactly what it was trying to look for and where.  Maybe using those can give you some clues

Comment: I don't get it. You get the error on command (1) or (2)? Where is 'test' used in any of these commands?

Comment: yano- I didn't saw ldd in my toolchain (I'm using arm-none-linux-gnueabi). Gustavo- I got the error when running ./test

Answer (score 0):

After digging a little bit I have found that a better approach would be to use NDK rather than standard Makefile for this purpose.

A comprehensive tutorial that helped me achieve what I want can be found at http://web.guohuiwang.com/technical-notes/androidndk1.

good luck